# My hardware MAC address is always 00:00:00:00:00:00 until I manually update 'eth0'. How can I fix this?

Tags: 12.04, networking, ethernet

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I use a wired connection. My network MAC address shows as `00:00:00:00:00:00`.

When I enter the commands below into a terminal window, it starts working again.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether my mac address
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

I have to enter these commands every time I want to use the Internet. How can I fix this?

---

**Update copied from comment**

The contents of my `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file  is:

```
[main] 
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile 
dns=dnsmasq 
no-auto-default=00:00:00:00:00:00,

[ifupdown] 
managed=false
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/74575/what-should-my-mac-address-be-now-shows-000000000000

Comment: I know my Mac address. When I put it in network connections nothing happens. I think that some bug has made 00:00:00:00:00:00 my default mac address.

Answer (score 1):

Could you clarify exactly what you mean when you say that your MAC is `00:00:00:00:00:00`.

What happens when you open the menu for Unity's Network Indicator, select `Edit Connections`, and then click on the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button for the `Wired` connection?

Do you see `00:00:00:00:00:00` as the **only** possible value for `Device MAC address`? (See example in the third (last) screenshot below.)

[image: screenshot of Network Indicator's menu]

[image: screenshot of Network Connections settings window]

[image: screenshot of edit window for Wired connection settings]

---

For whatever it is worth, the contents of my `NetworkManager.conf` file differs from yours. I do not have the entry `no-auto-default=00:00:00:00:00:00,`.

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Below is an excerpt from the online documentation for the [NetworkManager configuration](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html) file describing `no-auto-default`.

> Set devices for which NetworkManager  shouldn't  create  default wired
>   connection  (Auto eth0). NetworkManager creates a default wired
>   connection for  any  wired  device  that  is  managed  and doesn't 
>   have  a  connection  configured.  List a device in this option to 
>   inhibit  creating  the  default  connection  for  the device.

I am not sure that the `no-auto-default` entry is the cause of your problem. But you could still try the following just to rule it out.

- Create a backup copy of the file. One way to do this would be by using the *copy* command below.

  ```
  cd /etc/NetworkManager
  sudo cp NetworkManager.conf NetworkManager.conf.backup
  ```
- Use a text editor, for example `gedit`, to edit `NetworkManager.conf` and delete the `no-auto-default` line to see if it makes a difference.

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
  ```

Comment: I am new to ubuntu. Networkmanager conf file in etc/networkmanager is like this                                                                [main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=00:00:00:00:00:00,

[ifupdown]
managed=false                                                             I can type my mac address in network connections. When I save it nothing happens. It shows 00:00:00:00:00:00 as an option and when I click on it save option gets disabled.

Comment: @user57184 Would you please verify that using the GUI configuation windows give you the same results. If any changes were made, the GUI should almost certainly have been updated to work correctly since that would be considered to be the way most people would change their settings.

Comment: How to create a back up copy of Networkmanager.conf?

Comment: @irrationalJohn - please remove the questions in your answer.  Remember to use comments to ask for further details.

Comment: @user57184 - this is a Q&A site.  Please keep editing your question with important information such as the above - comments is not the best please for this type of info.  Thanks.

Comment: @fossfreedom If you would show me how I can fit the question I asked, complete with screenshots, into a comment then I will do this. Comments work for some things. Other questions IMO require more detail to clarify what is being asked. I do not know of any way to do the latter in a comment.

Comment: @user57184 Could you please add the output from the command `ifconfig -a -v` to your question? (You will have to edit your question to do this. It won't fit or format in a comment. Besides, as fossfreedom pointed out, extra details are best added by editing your question. See also this **[faq#howtoask]**.)

Comment: @user57184 Updated my answer again. Added `cp` to backup file.

Comment: @user57184 Is the correct MAC address shown in output from `sudo lshw -C network`? (It would be listed after `serial:`)